# XmlDocument.Validate not supported attributes or elements

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xmldocument, xml-validation

How can I get ValidationEvents if theire are attributes or elements in the xml that are not defined in the xsd.

**xsd:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsd:schema id="VoiceXmlTSPro"
                targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/VoiceXmlTSPro.xsd"
                elementFormDefault="qualified"
                xmlns="http://tempuri.org/VoiceXmlTSPro.xsd"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!-- Elements-->
    <xsd:element name="vxml">
     <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:attribute ref="base"/>
      <xsd:attribute ref="lang"/>
      </xsd:complexType>
     </xsd:element> 
       <!-- End Elements-->
       <!-- Attributes-->
       <xsd:attribute name="base" type="xsd:anyURI">
     </xsd:attribute>
     <xsd:attribute name="lang" type="xsd:string"> 
     </xsd:attribute>
    <!-- End Attributes-->
  </xsd:schema>
```

**xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
     <vxml application="notsupported" lang="en-US"     base="http://www.zebra.com">
       <unknow></unknow>
      </vxml>
```

I want a warning for the application attribute and for the unknow ellement.
But this code is not trowing any event.

```
    public override void Validate(string source)
    {
        ValidationResults.Clear();
        XmlSchemaFactory xmlSchemaFactory = new XmlSchemaFactory();
        XmlReaderSettings vxmlTestSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        vxmlTestSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        vxmlTestSettings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints| XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings ;
        try
        {
            XmlSchema xsdSchema = xmlSchemaFactory.Create(Resource.VoiceXmlTSPro);
            if (xmlSchemaFactory.HasErrors())
            {
                // if the schema is invalid the read wil not read
                return;
            }
            vxmlTestSettings.Schemas.Add(xsdSchema);
            ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationHandler);

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(source)))
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream, vxmlTestSettings))
            {
                XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
                document.Load(xmlReader);
                document.Validate(eventHandler);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what is your aim exactly, trying to validate a string with an XML instance document against a certain schema or schema set in the .NET framework? Or using the `Validate` method? And if the schema has `targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/VoiceXmlTSPro.xsd"`, why does your instance not declare that namespace? With your current instance document you would only get a warning about having no schema for the root element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to do is validate the string of XML markup against a schema then parsing the string with an `XmlReader` over a `StringReader` with proper `XmlReaderSettings` should do, there is no need to use an `XmlDocument` and its `Validate` method.

Here is an example, for the first sample it only outputs warnings as the input document has no namespace declaration, for the second document there are errors about undeclared element and attributes:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] xmls = { @"<vxml application=""notsupported"" lang=""en-US""     base=""http://www.zebra.com"">
   <unknow></unknow>
  </vxml>",
        @"<vxml application=""notsupported"" lang=""en-US""     base=""http://www.zebra.com"" xmlns=""http://example.com/ns1"">
   <unknow></unknow>
  </vxml>"
                        };

        foreach (string xml in xmls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Validating");
            Validate(xml, "../../schema1.xml");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static void Validate(string xmlMarkup, string schemaUri)
    {
        XmlReaderSettings xrs = new XmlReaderSettings();
        xrs.Schemas.Add(null, schemaUri);
        xrs.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        xrs.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
        xrs.ValidationEventHandler += (obj, valArgs) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", valArgs.Severity, valArgs.Message);
        };

        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlMarkup))
        {
            using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr, xrs))
            {
                while (xr.Read()) { }
            }
        }
    }
```

The schema is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<xsd:schema id="VoiceXmlTSPro"
                targetNamespace="http://example.com/ns1"
                elementFormDefault="qualified"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!-- Elements-->
    <xsd:element name="vxml">
     <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:attribute name="base" type="xsd:anyURI"/>
      <xsd:attribute name="lang" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:complexType>
     </xsd:element> 
       <!-- End Elements-->

  </xsd:schema>
```

the output is

```
Validating
Warning: Could not find schema information for the element 'vxml'.
Warning: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'application'.
Warning: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'lang'.
Warning: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'base'.
Warning: Could not find schema information for the element 'unknow'.

Validating
Error: The 'application' attribute is not declared.
Error: The element cannot contain white space. Content model is empty.
Error: The element 'http://example.com/ns1:vxml' cannot contain child element 'http://example.com/ns1:unknow' because the parent element's content model is empty.
```